# asp:Button inside SharePoint Dataview Rows with onclick event does not call C# function. Pull it out of Dataview and works fine

Tags: c#, sharepoint, row, dataview, buttonclick

asp:Button inside SharePoint Dataview Rows with onclick event does not call C# function. Pull it out of Dataview and works fine.

I have a ASP.NET Button I've placed inside a SharePoint  DataView's rows with an onclick event pointing to C# function block inside my page. The page refreshes when I click on them, but it's not hitting that code block. If I move the button to outside the dataview and make the ID fixed, the code works beautifully. what's up with that?

the button in the Dataview:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Delete" id="Delete{@ID}" CommandArgument="{@FileRef}" OnClick="DeleteDoc"/>
```

my C# onclick handler (inline C# on the page)

```
void DeleteDoc(object sender, EventArgs e){sendmail("DeleteDoc");Button b = sender as button;.. more code
```

This is all inline code and I'm working from SharePoint Designer. Not sure how I can troubleshoot this.

Am I missing something here, maybe I need to add an Itemtemplate or something like we need to in a ASP.NET gridview controls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRc, you need to use Actions, not events.

Comment: Thanks. I'm having trouble finding any good examples on how to do this. Will I be able to call a inline C# function from these actions? If not, i might as well redirect to a page that will delete the row and come back.

Comment: I'm playing with the DataView Add, Edit Delete buttons to see how dynamic we can make them.